# Is it possible to display the value of a known sibling within a template call?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a cut down snippet of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="WEEK-AYFM.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
  <Meeting>
    <LAC CircuitVisit="0">
      <SongEnd Title="“This Is the Way”" StartTime12="8:55" StartTime24="20:55" EndTime12="9:00" EndTime24="21:00">65</SongEnd>
      <PrayerEnd>Brother 8</PrayerEnd>
    </LAC>
  </Meeting>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

And this is some calling XSL:

```
  <xsl:template match="LAC">
    <table class="tableLAC">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SongEnd">
        <xsl:with-param name="strPrayerEnd">
          <xsl:value-of select="PrayerEnd"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SongEnd">
    <xsl:param name="strPrayerEnd" />
    <tr>
      <td class="cellTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="@EndTime24"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
          Prayer:
        </div>
        <span class="bulletLAC">&#8226;</span>
        <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$strPrayerEnd"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Is it possible for the **SongEnd** template to directly get access to the **PrayerEnd** value without me passing it as a **parameter**?

Comment: Please clarify: can a `LAC` contain more than one `SongEnd` and/or `PrayerEnd`? If yes, explain how will they be arranged within the `LAC` element.

Comment: It will only have one of each.

Comment: Then why don't you handle this while you are still in the context of `LAC`?  Apparently, your table will have only one row, so why not create it in the first template, then - if you want - apply templates to both children and have each create a cell. There is no need for this elaborate jumping in and out.

Comment: Hi. Could you show me what you mean please? Please note that I will have other data in the LAC node. I just cut it down to isolate my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, I believe you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Either one of the following stylesheets will produce the same result as your current one:

**1.**

```
<xsl:template match="LAC">
    <table class="tableLAC">
        <tr>
            <td class="cellTime">
                <xsl:value-of select="SongEnd/@EndTime24"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                  Prayer:
                </div>
                <span class="bulletLAC">&#8226;</span>
                <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">
                    <xsl:value-of select="SongEnd"/>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="PrayerEnd"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

**2.**

```
<xsl:template match="LAC">
    <table class="tableLAC">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="SongEnd"/>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="PrayerEnd"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SongEnd">
    <td class="cellTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
          Prayer:
        </div>
        <span class="bulletLAC">&#8226;</span>
        <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

**3.**

```
<xsl:template match="LAC">
    <table class="tableLAC">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SongEnd">
    <td class="cellTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
          Prayer:
        </div>
        <span class="bulletLAC">&#8226;</span>
        <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PrayerEnd">      
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I used option 2. I will see if I can do this elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In the template which matches `SongEnd` the context node is a `SongEnd` element. You can then use a simple XPath expression to select the `PrayerEnd` node in the template with respect to the context node.

For instance if the `PrayerEnd` is always the following sibling of `SongEnd` you can write

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::PrayerEnd"/>
```

without using the parameter.

Comment: That works well, thank you. The PrayerEnd node will always follow the SongEnd node.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, if this resolved your issue consider marking the answer as accepted (tick box under the vote rocker).  It will help future users find the answer more quickly.